Telegram ConversationHandler triggering inside another file

https://pastebin.com/6WVaqhuf - this is the auth.py


https://pastebin.com/1ct9pyrB - this is the sign.up

I was creating a conversation inside sign_up.py and wanted to trigger after user's choice from sign up or sign in which is inside auth.py So I thought if I call the entry_point function of sign_up.py, which is start_sign_up function, i would be able to trigger the whole conversation process but it is not triggering. What should I do to do trigger the whole process?
